# Circular Android Selector

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to allow my app to support multiple themes and am currently working on an interface that will show all of these themes before the user picks one.

I was wondering if it was possible to make something resembling this:
[image]

If so, how would I go about doing so? I imagine that it would involve a tabbed activity but apart from that I have no clue. And a google search isn't helping out all too much :/

Comment: Yeah dude I am not opening a PNG link with "skin" in its name as well as 18 at work. Post it to your question.

Comment: LOL I didn't even think about that. Will do lmao

Comment: This is more work than you think ;-) See me answer.. But you will need to do a lot of surface / openGL type work. At that point you might as well do this in Unity.

Comment: I assumed as much, thanks a bunch for the reply! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I can't help you with the fancy bowed look. For that you need to do a custom rendering with a surface view.. That said if you are okay with it flat.. (Some libraries might take you a step closer) You can do a simple HORIZONTAL Recyclerview.. My implementation uses a custom view pager to swap between. However you can ignore that section, marked at 2

Section 1 the tabber UI

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/custom_tab_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/tab_layout"
/>
```

I cant show UI for tab_layout as its stupidly customized over a period of 4 months. But the point is it is Vertical

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
> ...
```

Code implementation

```
  @Override
    public void TabItemSelected(int position) {
    mCustomTabAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
    mCustomTabAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mCustomTabBarRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
    mPageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mCustomTabBarRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
}
```

in my ui creation

```
            mCustomTabBarRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCustomTabAdapter);
            mCustomTabBarRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mCustomTabBarRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Section 2 the view pager. [I think I based it off this vogella example](https://github.com/vogellacompany/codeexamples-android/tree/master/de.vogella.android.fragment.viewpager)

```
  <xx.xx.CustomViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/xx_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
/>
```

CUSTOM PAGER

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;

}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;

}

}
```

SETUP

```
 mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(getPageChangeListener());
            mPageAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(getFragmentManager(),
                    mMemberArrayList);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);


   private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener getPageChangeListener() {

    return new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
            mCustomTabAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
            mCustomTabAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mCustomTabBarRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

        }
    };
}
```

CUSTOM ADAPTER

```
public class UserProfileAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Member> mMemberArrayList = null;
private final DashboardFragment[] mFragments;

/**
 * Build the set of fragments that we need for the view pages.
 */
public UserProfileAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Member> arrayList) {
    super(fm);
    mMemberArrayList = arrayList;
    mFragments = new DashboardFragment[arrayList.size()];
    DashboardFragment.setDataSource(arrayList);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        mFragments[i] = DashboardFragment.newInstance(i);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    if (mMemberArrayList == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return mMemberArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    return "Pos: " + position;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments[position];
}
}
```